# Notepad++ Replace Iteration

Tags: notepad++, regex

(I have edited this post for clarity)

I have a terribly formatted text document.. Luckily, though terribly formatted, it's reliably terribly formatted and so regex has saved me days worth of work.

I'm now at the point that I want to provide bookmarks for the table of contents to link to I've managed to replace each section title with

```
<a name="#insertlinkhere">Assembly</a>
Content under Assembly title.
<a name="#insertlinkhere">Warranty</a>
Content under Warranty title.
<a name="#insertlinkhere">Contact</a>
...
```

And the like.. each occurrence of insertlinkhere is literally insertlinkhere.

Now what I want to do is replace each `insertlinkhere`\ with an 'a' + *iteration-count*, so the first three would say

```
<a name="#a1">Assembly</a>
...
<a name="#a2">Warranty</a>
...
<a name="#a3">Contact</a>
...


<a name="#a48">Assemblage</a>
...
<a name="#a49">Garantie</a>
...
```

I have googled for this, but I'm not sure my terminology is correct or possibly, notepad++ is not capable of this without a specific addon. Perhaps someone could suggest a program that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continued searching while waiting for an answer showed me that TextPad can do *incrementalreplace* simply enter your Find string (`insertlinkhere` in my case) and your replace string `a\i` where \i automatically increments for each replace iteration.

Hope it helps someone else.

Comment: It's not working

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this in Notepad++ with two steps

**step1:**
Replace (ctrl+h) the word "insertlinkhere" with "a"

```
<a name="#insertlinkhere">Assembly</a>
<a name="#insertlinkhere">Warranty</a>
<a name="#insertlinkhere">Contact</a>
```

output:

```
<a name="#a">Assembly</a>
<a name="#a">Warranty</a>
<a name="#a">Contact</a>
```

**Step2:**

Now select the word **#a** , so that your cursor should be in end of a.

From the Edit menu (**ALT+C** keyboard shortcut) in your notepad++. Change the radio button to Number to Insert with a starting value of 1 incrementing by 1 (Decimal). Confirm using the OK button. You should end up with this:

```
<a name="#a1">Assembly</a>
<a name="#a2">Warranty</a>
<a name="#a3">Contact</a>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work, and it's my fault for not properly explaining that there are gaps between each anchor line.. that column is incremented each row. Thanks for the effort though!